# Перевести код jQuery на чистый javaScript

Tags: jquery, javascript

Мне нужен код на чистом javascript, никак не могу сообразить

```
var x = $('div.class :eq(160)').html();
```

вот мне значение этого х и надо получить, но на чистом javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

попробуй так, но я не уверен что это то же самое, что и на jquery

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('class')[160];
x = x.innerHTML;
```

Comment: Спасибо)
я еще придумал так:

var el = document.querySelectorAll('div.class');
el = el[160];
el = el.innerHTML;

Comment: В данном решении упущен div, то есть в общем случае результат может быть не тем